# How to Resolve "Inconsistent JVM-target compatibility" Error After Recently Updating Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I recently updated my Flutter, but I'm encountering the Execution failed for task ':flutter_image_compress_common:compileDebugKotlin'. > Inconsistent JVM-target compatibility error. Below is the code from my android/build.gradle and app/build.gradle files:

android/build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.9.21'
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.2.0'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
}}
```

app/build.gradle:

```
compileOptions {
coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled true
sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
}
kotlinOptions {
jvmTarget = '17'}
```

Flutter --version:

```
Flutter 3.16.3 • channel stable • 
Framework • revision b0366e0a3f (8 days ago) • 2023-12-05 19:46:39 -0800
Engine • revision 54a7145303
Tools • Dart 3.2.3 • DevTools 2.28.4
```